# Trying to remove randomly selected teams from a list. Works for first 5 teams, but after that the teams start to repeat

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop

My objective is to choose 2 random teams from a txt file, make sure they aren't from the same school, pair them together, and then remove them from the array so they aren't chosen again. It works for the first 5 pairs, but after that I start getting repeated teams. I'll include the txt file that I'm getting the teams from below the code. Sorry if my code is sloppy, this is my first semester writing code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // SYSTEMS FILE SHOULD BE IN < >
#include <time.h>            

//function to print school names, not being used at the time
void printNamesAs2DStringS( char myData[ ] [4] , int row, int col )
{
  int i = 0 , j;
  printf ("Printing as 2D String\n");

  for ( i = 0 ; i < row; i++) 
  {
    printf ( "%s", myData[i]  );
    printf ( "\n");
  }
}

//getting 2 random numbers
void get2Teams ( int *i, int*j, int count)
{
  while (1)
  {
    // grabbing 2 teams
    int x = rand() % count;
    int y = rand() % count;
    if ( x != y)
    {
      *i = x;
      *j = y;
      return;
    }            
  }
} 

int main() 
{
  char names[32][4] = {0}; 

  int i;
  char temp[4];//temp array to store team name
  int numOfTeams =0;//number of teams

  FILE *fp, *fw ; //made a pointer to read and write.

  fp = fopen ( "provision.txt", "r");//open file for read
  fw = fopen ( "round1_pairings.txt", "w");//opens round 1 pairings to write to it

  if ( fp != NULL ) 
  {      
    int num = fscanf ( fp, "%s", temp);

    while ( num != EOF) 
    {
      strcpy ( names[numOfTeams] , temp);

      numOfTeams++;

      num = fscanf ( fp, "%s", temp);
    }//end of while    
  }//end of if


  //selecting 2 random teams
  //char names[32] [4] ;
  int a, b;

  srand ( time(NULL) );
  fprintf (fw, "ROUND 1\n \n");

  for(i = 1;i <= 32;i++ )
  {              
    get2Teams ( &a, &b, 32);

    //checks to see if the teams are from the same school
    if (strncmp(names[a], names[b], 2) == 0)
    {
      //if teams are from the same school, fetches new pair
      get2Teams ( &a, &b, 32);          
    }
    else
    {                    
      fprintf (fw, "%s vs.", names[a]);
      fprintf (fw, "%s\n", names[b]); 
      printf ( "a=%s b=%s \n", names[a], names[b]);//prints out pair
      strcpy(names[a], names[a+1]);//removes team a and shrinks array
      strcpy(names[b], names[b+1]);//removes team b and shrinks array
    } 
  }

  //number of teams
  printf (" Number of Teams %d \n", numOfTeams);

  fclose(fw);//close files
  fclose(fp);
}
```

These are the teams that I am randomly selecting, the teams from the same schools are in the same rows and they start with the same two letters.

> ABA ABC ABD ABG
>     BAA BAB BAC
>     CAB CBA
>     DAB DBC DBE DBA
>     EAB
>     FAB FAC FAA
>     GAB GAA
>     HAA HAB
>     IAB
>     JAA
>     KAA
>     LAL LAB
>     MAA MAB MBA MUM
>     NAN NAB

Comment: Your code for removing a team looks wrong. `strcpy(names[a], names[a+1])` that will just result in two copies of `names[a+1]` in the array. Nowhere do you invalidate any of the entries even though your comment claims to "shrink" the array. And shrinking won't work anyway because the chosen team is not necessarily at the end of the array. You need a way of marking teams as chosen (e.g. replace the name with an empty string).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was under the impression that it was replacing names[a] with the next team in the array. 

if this is the array:
ABA ABB ADB ACB
and ABB was chosen, I was just trying to copy ADB and put it in its place. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That's exactly what you are doing. But the result would then be `ABA ADB ADB ACB`. That is, two copies of `ADB`. Clearly not what you want right? Instead you could for example do `names[a][0]='\0'` to null out the name. Then your `get2Teams` should check for that and retry until it gets two non-empty names.